# How to access "locale" value (of an Internationalization App) in server side in GWT?

Tags: gwt, gwtp

Ok, I am developing an app that supports Internationalization. I am using `Static String Internationalization` method for my app.

Let say my app can have English & German version, so 
-1st, I created `MyMessages.java` which has all message texts written in English. Then I created an `MyMessages_ge` which is almost the same as `MyMessages.java` except that the text written in German

-2nd, in `MyProject.html` i have `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">` to make sure it will support all languages

-3rd, in `MyProject.gwt.xml` I have `<extend-property name="locale" values="ge"/>`

Now I run my app in eclipse `http://localhost:8888/MyProject.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997&locale=ge` & it shows all the German text as I expected.

However, I have a need to know that my app is German `At Server Side`. That means whenever my GWT Gui in German version then my server will know that `languageCode=1` if it is in English so server will use the default language `languageCode=0`

Here is what I did. At `HeaderPresenter.java`

```
@Override
public void prepareFromRequest(PlaceRequest request){
    super.prepareFromRequest(request);
    String locale=request.getParameter("locale", "");
    setLanguage(locale); // servercall back here
}
```

so when my app run first time it should let server to know which language the Gwt app is using

```
@Override
public SetLanguageResult execute(SetLanguage action, ExecutionContext context)
        throws ActionException {
    String locale=action.getLocale();
    if("ge".equals(locale)){
        Data.languageType=1;
    }
    return null;
}
```

However, it doesn't seem work
When I go to orderPage the url will be `http://localhost:8888/MyProject.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997&locale=ge#!orderPage` it not in the form `http://localhost:8888/MyProject.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997#!orderPage;locale=ge` that is why server couldn't capture the `locale` value.

I think I misunderstood something here. I'm quite confusing.

So How to access "locale" value (of an Internationalization App) in server side in GWT?

Comment: The two letter country code for Germany is **de** not **ge**. The code **ge** refers to Georgia. Just saying...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a utility class to deal with locale information in the GWT SDK. No need to parse URL parameters yourself. Have a look at [LocaleInfo.getCurrentLocale()](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/LocaleInfo.html) then use the *getLocaleName()* method to get the actual code as a String.

I have not quite understand how you store the locale information on the server side? Mind that servlets are shared between users, you have to attach the local to the session or pass it with every call.

Comment: great this is almost done, but how to get the current locale? i couldn't see any getcurrent? I want thing like this String locale=LocaleInfo.getCurrentLocale(); if("de".equals(locale)) then ....

Comment: I found LocaleInfo localeInfo=LocaleInfo.getCurrentLocale();
  String locale=localeInfo.getLocaleName();
     addToPopupSlot(loadingPresenter);
     SetLanguage action=new SetLanguage(locale);
         
     dispatchAsync.execute(action, setLanguageCallback);

Thax you very much